# Mostrar soma de coluna do usuario logado. erro

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, mysqli

Bom dia pessoal, alguem me ajuda? eu nao entendo muito de php, mas para eu finalizar o meu site falta apenas uma coisa: preciso postar a soma dos valores que estão na tabela mas com base no usuário logado, ja tentei de todas as formas mas nao consigo segue o ultimo que testei:

```
<?php    
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'user_login';
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM investimentos WHERE usuario= usuario");

    //Passa o ID do usuário para a query
    $sql->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['user_login'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    $ln = $sql->fetchObject();
    echo $ln->total;    
?>
```

ja tentei de tudo nem pegar apenas valores da coluna sem ser por usuáiro logado consigo a pagina fica toda em branco.

Comment: voce ta criando uma variavel de sessao como uma string 'user_login'..

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema está na sua query. No final "WHERE usuario= usuario", o usuario está como uma string. Você precisa deixar como uma variável, desse jeito: '$usuario'.

Eu nunca utilizei PHP dessa forma, orientado a objetos, mas acho que isso deve resolver.

Comment: infelismente nao adiantou nao gera nada para mim fica apenas em branco, já estou desistindo esta tenso, e nao acho outra forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM investimentos WHERE usuario= $usuario");
```

Comment: nadinha esta complicado isso

Answer (score 0):

acredito que o seu problema seja na hora de passar o valor para ser substituido na query.

```
$sql->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['user_login'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

A linha acima ira substituir o primeiro caracter "?" da sua query pelo segundo paramêtro passado na chamada do método bindValue que no seu caso é $_SESSION['user_login'], no entanto a sua query não possui o caracter "?". Portanto você deve substituir sua query pela seguinte:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM investimentos WHERE usuario = ?");
```

Comment: continua a mesma coisa será que devo fazer a chamada para o banco de dados? só nao sei como fazer corretamente

Comment: Está recebendo alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Adicione o seguinte código na primeira linha após abrir a tag php para exibir os erros:

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: apareceu esse erro: Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_21930618/fastinvest.ml/htdocs/teste1.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_21930618/fastinvest.ml/htdocs/teste1.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_21930618/fastinvest.ml/htdocs/teste1.php on line 3
 e a linha 3 é a do SELECT

Comment: Pela mensagem recebida o erro está na variável $pdo, elá não esta inicializada por exemplo: $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");

Comment: quanto testo da erro na linha do Execute()

Comment: Tem como mostrar o errro? o código inteiro também

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_21930618/fastinvest.ml/htdocs/teste.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_xxxxxx/fastinvest.ml/htdocs/teste.php(3): PDO->__construct('sql300.epizy.co...', 'epiz_xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'epiz_21xxxxxxx_w...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/vol14_5/epizy.com/epiz_xxxxxxxx/fastinvest.ml/htdocs/teste.php on line 3 esse é o bendito erro

Comment: Conforme a mensagem de erro é por que você está passando um quarto paramêtro no construtor do PDO. Você deve chamar ele da seguinte forma: $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");  substituindo o "localhost" pelo seu ip do servidor e o "database" pelo nome do banco de dados do seu servidor, como poder ver é passado somente 3 parametros, o dns, username e password.

Answer (score 0):

Tente substituir o parâmetro do PDO desta maneira:

```
<?php    
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = 'user_login';
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM investimentos WHERE usuario= :usuario");

    //Passa o ID do usuário para a query
    $sql->bindValue(':usuario', $_SESSION['user_login'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    $ln = $sql->fetchObject();
    echo $ln->total;    
?>
```

certifique-se que a variável da sessão está vindo correta, adicione algum var_dump ou print_r para ver qual o valor dela, e siga em frente.